# Requests python- Autenticacion fallida NOT support JavaScript

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import requests, json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
responseGet = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pass), timeout=None, headers=headers)
```

Pero me responde con esto

```
responseGet.content

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#666666" onLoad="loadnext()"> 
<form name="login" method="POST" action="">
<div ID="maintext" STYLE="position:absolute;left:50px;top:40px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica">
<h4>Checking JavaScript Support </h4>
<p>To provide an enhanced user interface, this Device uses JavaScript extensively.
<P>If this page is not quickly replaced, your Browser does NOT support JavaScript.
<P>Please enable JavaScript in your Browser, or use a different Browser. </p>
```

Creí que era por los `headers` por lo que veo no es eso, Como me salto esta advertencia?

Comment: Echa un ojo [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages) a ver si te ayuda.